# Implications of plowing a perennial grassland in winter

Tags: winter-gardening

I'm currently managing a perennial grassland that has been established for several years, serving as a habitat for various plants and potentially supporting biodiversity. I'm considering plowing a portion of this grassland during the winter for specific reasons, but I'm concerned about the potential consequences.

I'd like to understand the implications of plowing a perennial grassland, particularly in the winter season.

Following garden plan I implemented:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason the norm of mowing once in Spring is too simple? Plowing is not the natural route and will actually unearth weeds.

Comment: So you would advice plowing once before implementing the garden, and afterwards only mowing once in Spring?!

Comment: No one plows perennials unless they want to kill them. Do you mean mowing instead? If so, then springtime is the time to do that.

Comment: You can till lightly without plowing heavily, which breaks native water exchange. See *Plowman's Folly*.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are considering plowing under a portion of your perennial grassland in the winter to plant a planned garden in the spring.

My first advice to you is to contact agriculturists / farmers in your area and ask them for advice.  They will give you far better information than I can.  They know your local soil, water, and climate better than I do, and have actual experience with it.  [Plowing is a big subject](https://smallfarmersjournal.com/the-science-and-art-of-plowing/#:%7E:text=Late%20fall%20and%20winter%20plowing,to%20become%20settled%20before%20seeding.)!

What I would consider:

- Fall / Autumn is a common time to plow.  Plowing frozen ground in the winter is not always practicable, but is also done.
- The vegetable matter and chaos you plow into the soil will need time to settle before it is suitable for planting.
- Your soil may require additional tillage, probably in the spring time, to be suitable for planting.
- If you intend to do any soil conditioning, when you plow may be a good time to incorporate the additions.
- You may get new weeds growing that you haven't seen before when deep, dormant seeds are turned up to the surface.